# Magento 2 checkout page showing "No items to ship found in rates request" error

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I'm new in Magento. I have purchased a theme and setup it.

After that, I have uploaded some products, but I can't complete the order process.

When I tried to order it showing below error in Payment Review section.

Below I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: which Magento 2 version you are using? looks like system having lots of unnecessary modules. You can disable all unrelevant modules https://www.yireo.com/blog/2018-05-23-disabling-annoying-3rd-party-magento-modules